# Choice field values returning as string with "\n". How to get collection?

Tags: development, rest, json

While parsing data returned from REST, the **Choice field** values are returning as `Edm.string` with "\n".

I want the results in `collection(Edm.string)`.

Current result :

```
{"__metadata": {"type":"SPKeyValue"},

"Key" :"MultiChoiceField", 

"Value":"first\n\nthird",

"ValueType":"Edm.String"}
```

Comment: What's your request look like? My multi-choice results have always come back as a collection, not a string.

Comment: @wjervis my request look like this . localhost//_api/search/postquery {"request":{"__metadata":{"type":"Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchReque‌​st"},"Querytext":"and(Title:starts-with(Test),filter(contenttypeid:0x0101*))","En‌​ableFQL":"true","SelectProperties":{"results":["Url","ContentType","SPWebURL","SP‌​SiteURL","ListID","ListItemID","Created","Title","MultiChoiceField"]},"StartRow":‌​0,"RowsPerPage":20,"RowLimit":20, "TrimDuplicates":"True"}}

Comment: Ah, didn't realize this was search.  Odd, my multi-choice for search comes back as a string in the format: `choice1;#choice2`, with the ;# delimiter, not \n\n.

Comment: ohhh, Can you paste your request? . what changes should I do get the result like yours?. Thanks for the help

Comment: My request is different, since I use GET instead of POST, but here's what it looks like: `/_api/search/query?selectProperties='Title,Path,YearsOWSCHCM'&queryText='Path:https://sharepoint.com'`.  The value for YearsOWSCHCM appears as `2015;#2016;#`.  **Edit**: I tested with a POST, and it returns the same way.

Comment: @wjervis, I am using SharePoint 2013 . Are you using the same?

Comment: I am in SharePoint Online, so  yes.

Comment: Any idea ? why it is coming  like this with \n.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to convert search value (`SPKeyValue` type) into choice field value (`collection(Edm.string)` type) once the search results are returned.

**JavaScript example**

```
function castToChoiceValue(searchValue) {
    if (searchValue.Key == "MultiChoiceField") {
        var value = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
            },
            "results": searchValue.Value.split("\n").filter(function (v) { return v })
        };
        return value;
    }
    return searchValue;
}
```

Usage

```
var searchValue = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SPKeyValue" },

    "Key": "MultiChoiceField",

    "Value": "first\n\nthird",

    "ValueType": "Edm.String"
};


var choiceValue = castToChoiceValue(searchValue);
console.log(choiceValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But there are many multi choice fields and I will not be knowing name of all multi choice fields and string fields. This is Fast search query result in Rest. any other go ?

Thank you Vijiyo